# Update on FK column

Tags: sql

I have db with more than 5000 product for X vendor, I have vendor_id which is foreign key. I need to update the products table to set all of this products to another vendor. I can see in products table field called vendor_id close to each product with same value. is there update statement to update this field with tow vendor_id values. 
many thanks

Comment: You have tagged both MySQL and Oracle; they are different RDBMS - which is it? Also, please provide a [MCVE] with the DDL statements for your tables, DML statements for some sample data and your expected output (following the update) and, most importantly, what **YOU** have tried to solve the problem and details of where it is not correct.

Comment: Something like this? UPDATE Products SET vendor_id = 42 WHERE vendor_id = 1. Otherwise I'm not really sure what you're asking. If you have 1 field called vendor_id, then you cannot store 2 vendor_ids in there. If you have 1 for vendor_id, and one for vendor_id_old, you could store 2

Comment: @mohammad-kanaan - Your description is far too vague. What do you mean you need to set them to another vendor while also keeping them on the current vendor? Do you want to end up with 10k products? If so, how would you distinguish between the old products and the new products, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```
update products
set vendor_id = second_vendor_id
where vendor_id = first_vendor_id
```

Comment: I need to set all of these products to another vendor with keep this products to current vendor also.
I mean 5000 products for tow vendors

Comment: You want another 5000 records with second vendor_id or in one vendor_id you want to store both vendor ids ?

Comment: can you contact me via skype, I'll show you 
Skype ID: M7mad kan3an 
location: Jordan